# Binding result from AutoCompleteTextbox

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

I'm using this wpf control: https://wpfautocomplete.codeplex.com/

The control takes user input and calls a method which returns a IEnumerable from MaquinasSuggestionProvider which is actually a List. A Template is made to show this results, and the ID is displayed on the textbox.

What I need is that after the user selects the correct suggestion, the object Maquina from that list is binded to the actual datacontext, which has a property of that type, so that other properties of Maquina are displayed on labels.

```
<wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox x:Name="tboxId"
        Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="2" Text="" Watermark="Ingresar valor"
        Provider="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MaquinasSuggestionProvider}"
        DisplayMember="ID"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MaquinaTemplate}"
        RenderTransformOrigin="1.333,-1.13" FontSize="32" 
        KeyDown="tboxId_KeyDown" Margin="0,6,0,0" Height="52" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="tboxId_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" d:IsLocked="True"/>

<Label x:Name="lbDescripcion2" Content="{Binding Path=Maquina.Descripcion}" Grid.Column="5" Margin="0,58,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="302" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" d:IsLocked="True"/>
```

I don't understand where I must specify that the selected object from the suggestion list must be assigned to the current datacontext.

I tried to make a workaround, assigning an event when the user clicks the suggestion and then manually creating the object Maquina and asigning it to the datacontext, but I couldn't find an event that fires upon selection. Since this application runs in a tablet, user input comes not from keyboard but from a wpf-made on screen keyboard.

[image: example]

Thanks in advance.

edit: ItemTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MaquinaTemplate" DataType="Modelo:Maquina">
        <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=StackPanelStyle}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Descripcion}"/>
            <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

edit: not duplicate since I'm not using Silverlight, and I'm not using AutoCompleteBox but the wpf control I linked at the beginning of the post.

Comment: added ItemTemplate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Autocompletebox MVVM how to get selectedItem from another control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801441/wpf-autocompletebox-mvvm-how-to-get-selecteditem-from-another-control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simply as adding this line in the AutoCompleteTextBox:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Maquina, Mode=TwoWay}"
```